# Load all tab view when lunch the application

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I am using "support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost". I have two tab in my main activity

```
  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            FragmentTab1.class, null); 
 mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
            FragmentTab2.class, null);
```

Usually first create the FragmentTab1 View. Then press the second tab(Contacts) then create the FragmentTab2 veiw

I want that both view will create after lunch the application without any click on any Tab. How it is possible? Please help me......

Actually I want to show some run time generated data from service.

Comment: Why do you want to lunch the application and why not launch ;)